# Drag and drop in API level 9

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

Can I implement drag and drop in Android API level 9? Is there any jar file so that I can use it in API level 9 and above?

Answer (score 3):

In the link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Under quick view it is said that drag and drop requires API 11

```
**Quickview**

    Allow users to move data within your Activity layout using graphical gestures.
    Supports operations besides data movement.
    Only works within a single application.
    Requires API 11.
```